# How do I blacklist files in .tproject using Tizen Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-tv, tizen-studio, tizen-tv

**Disclaimer:** I have no idea what I am doing here.

I was given a project with a large .tproject file (7956 lines). This is because it is blacklisting numerous files that shouldn't build. It's mostly node_modules. Each file in a module is blacklisted.

Making sure I have installed the node packages, I have followed these steps:

- Remove blacklist node from .tproject
- Open Tizen Sudio (2.3) on Windows 10
- File > Open Projects from File System
- Show other specialized import wizards
- Tizen > Tizen Project
- Browse root directory location
- Profile > tv
- Finish *(project is created but modal hasn't closed)*

I get this message:

```
   Resource '/project' already exists
```

and then:

```
    Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Tizen Web Builder' on project 'DStv Now'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

> **What I want to know:**
>
> - To get the NullPointerException, my project is definitely missing something in order to get setup. Any ideas what could be missing?
> - How do I import the project as a Tizen TV application?
> - How is the .tproject file created?
> - Is it a suitable file to add to .gitignore? It looks auto generated.
> - If not, is there a way to use regex to blacklist files instead of listing them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

What I know about .tproject is, It holds Project template Information. Like : tv-samsung-3.0, wearable-2.3.2. This will change only when the developer changes the template for some reason (Suppose update app for new tizen version).

About Importing Tizen TV Project->

Tizen-Studio > File > Import > Tizen > Tizen Project > Root Directory >
**Select Specific Project Folder**

If every-thing's okay till now you would see a project on Project list. Set the Profile and Version, then finish. The project should be on your Tizen-Studio Project Explorer. Project > Clean > Build.

About .gitignore what I can suggest is to add only the files that get removed at Clean Project command.